# How to stop at a specific branch/level in an Oracle Tree Hierarchy?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, tree, oracle11g

Given the following tree hierarchy example in Oracle 11gr2:

Query:

```
SELECT Lpad(ename,Length(ename) + LEVEL * 10 - 10,'-') 
FROM   emp 
START WITH mgr IS NULL 
CONNECT BY PRIOR empno = mgr


Result:


KING
----------JONES
--------------------SCOTT
------------------------------ADAMS
--------------------FORD
------------------------------SMITH
----------BLAKE
--------------------ALLEN
--------------------WARD
--------------------MARTIN
--------------------TURNER
--------------------JAMES
----------SAM
--------------------MILLER
```

I need to prune my tree query so that whenever the ename starts with the character 'S', `i.e. substr(ename,1,1) = 'S'`, display this value/branch but then ignore everyhting below that, i.e. don't display anything further after this level.

So based on the above result sample, new result sample would look like:

```
New Result:

KING
----------JONES
--------------------SCOTT
--------------------FORD
------------------------------SMITH
----------BLAKE
--------------------ALLEN
--------------------WARD
--------------------MARTIN
--------------------TURNER
--------------------JAMES
----------SAM
```

So the children "ADAMS" and "MILLER" have been removed from new result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Lpad(ename,Length(ename) + LEVEL * 10 - 10,'-') 
FROM   emp 
START WITH mgr IS NULL 
CONNECT BY PRIOR empno = mgr and substr(PRIOR ename,1,1) <> 'S';
```

Or if you want to use [Recursive subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55268):

```
with employees(empno, ename, mgr, emp_level) as
(
    select empno, ename, mgr, 1 emp_level
    from emp
    where mgr is null
    union all
    select emp.empno, emp.ename, emp.mgr, emp_level+1 emp_level
    from emp
    join employees
        on emp.mgr = employees.empno
    where substr(employees.ename,1,1) <> 'S'
) search depth first by empno set order1
select Lpad(ename,Length(ename) + emp_level * 10 - 10,'-')
from employees
order by order1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8bf5/1)